# When were F# unused reserved keywords removed from the specs?

Tags: .net, f#, keyword

I've read from an article from F# Github before that some of unused reserved keywords had been removed, such as `params`, and we should use attributes instead.

From the [Keyword Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/keyword-reference) page, I can't find those removed keywords, where am I able to search for them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read about them in the [RFC over at the fslang-design repo](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp-4.1/FS-1016-unreserve-keywords.md). The unreserved keywords are:

- **method**  - the F# community is happy with `member` to introduce methods.
- **constructor** - the F# community is happy with `new` to introduce constructors.
- **atomic** - this was related to the fad for transactional memory circa 2006. In F# this would now be a library-defined computation expression.
- **eager** - this is no longer needed, it was initially designed to be `let eager` to match a potential `let lazy`.
- **object**  - there is no need to reserve this.
- **recursive**  - F# is happy using `rec`.
- **functor**  - If F# added parameterized modules, we would use `module M(args) = ...`.
- **measure**  - There is no specific reason to reserve this these days, the `[<Measure>]` attribute suffices.
- **volatile** - There is no specific reason to reserve this these days, the `[<Volatile>]` attribute suffices.

This made it into F# 4.1.

Comment: What about `params`, when was it removed?

Comment: Since [`params` is mentioned in the F# 4 specification](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf) (page 28) and it is not on the list of unreserved keywords, that means: `params` is still a reserved keyword. You can test this by launching the latest F# Interactive 4.1 and typing `let params = 1;;`, which prints the warning `warning FS0046: The identifier 'params' is reserved for future use by F#`.

Comment: Then I hope someone from Microsoft can update the `Keyword Reference` page, like `eager`, `object` aren't removed or `params` isn't listed.

Comment: `[<Volatile>]`? I guess that is a typo, isn't it `[<VolatileField>]`?See https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-volatilefieldattribute.html